# Colunas com números de linhas diferentes, como juntar?

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho algumas séries temporais (mensais) que terminam em meses diferentes, por exemplo, algumas terminam em março 2017, outras em abril 2017 e algumas até em maio de 2017, segue exemplo:

```
228 2016-12-01      1.12
229 2017-01-01      1.09
230 2017-02-01      0.87
231 2017-03-01      1.05
232 2017-04-01      0.79
233 2017-05-01      0.08



    data       v7827
206 2016-10-01 12.36
207 2016-11-01 12.37
208 2016-12-01 11.84
209 2017-01-01 11.11
210 2017-02-01 10.53
211 2017-03-01  9.85



  data          v3698
227 2016-11-01 3.3420
228 2016-12-01 3.3523
229 2017-01-01 3.1966
230 2017-02-01 3.1042
231 2017-03-01 3.1279
232 2017-04-01 3.1362
```

Preciso juntá-las em um único data.frame, porém, usando um cbind, resulta em erro pois o número de linhas é diferente. Como eu posso fazer um join entre essas tabelas para transformá-las em uma só de uma maneira simplificada? Sem precisar ficar adicionando valores nas datas vazias? O resultado final esperado é esse:

```
                            v7827   v3698
228 2016-12-01      1.12    11.84   3.3523
229 2017-01-01      1.09    11.11   3.1966
230 2017-02-01      0.87    10.53   3.1042
231 2017-03-01      1.05    9.85    3.1279
232 2017-04-01      0.79            3.1362
233 2017-05-01      0.08
```

Comment: Obrigada galera, vcs me salvaram de um trabalhao de mais de 2 dias que estava pensando e enlouquecendo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podem-se juntar várias bases só com o R base.
Como a função `merge` só aceita duas `data.frame`'s quando há mais que duas têm que ser postas numa lista e faz-se a função `Reduce` chamar o `merge`.

Com o exemplo dos dados da pergunta, vou supor que as bases estão no `.GlobalEnv` e portanto vou primeiro criar uma lista com elas.

```
df_list <- ls(pattern = "^df\\d+$")  # Encontra os nomes das df's
df_list <- mget(df_list)             # Vai buscar os objetos com esses nomes
```

Agora é só uma linha de código.

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE), df_list)
#        data v1234 v7827  v3698
#1 2016-10-01    NA 12.36     NA
#2 2016-11-01    NA 12.37 3.3420
#3 2016-12-01  1.12 11.84 3.3523
#4 2017-01-01  1.09 11.11 3.1966
#5 2017-02-01  0.87 10.53 3.1042
#6 2017-03-01  1.05  9.85 3.1279
#7 2017-04-01  0.79    NA 3.1362
#8 2017-05-01  0.08    NA     NA
```

**Dados.**

Note que na pergunta a primeira df não tem cabeçalho de colunas, usei `data` e `v` seguido de um número qualquer.

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
    data           v1234
228 2016-12-01      1.12
229 2017-01-01      1.09
230 2017-02-01      0.87
231 2017-03-01      1.05
232 2017-04-01      0.79
233 2017-05-01      0.08
", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
    data       v7827
206 2016-10-01 12.36
207 2016-11-01 12.37
208 2016-12-01 11.84
209 2017-01-01 11.11
210 2017-02-01 10.53
211 2017-03-01  9.85
", header = TRUE)

df3 <- read.table(text = "
  data          v3698
227 2016-11-01 3.3420
228 2016-12-01 3.3523
229 2017-01-01 3.1966
230 2017-02-01 3.1042
231 2017-03-01 3.1279
232 2017-04-01 3.1362
", header = TRUE)

df1$data <- as.Date(df1$data)
df2$data <- as.Date(df2$data)
df3$data <- as.Date(df3$data)
```

Answer (score 4):

Eu simulei algumas bases para exemplificar o que vc quer, por favor avise se houver alguma inconsistência:

As bases com 3 e 4 linhas, onde as valores iguais são `a1` e `a2` (no seu caso são as datas):

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  data=c("a1", "a2", "a3"),
  b=c("b1", "b2", "b3"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  data=c("a1", "a2", "a4", "a5"),
  c=c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

Agora eu extraio as datas únicas e faço um `left_join()` do `dplyr` para adicionar as colunas:

```
datas <- as.data.frame(unique(c(df1$data, df2$data)), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(datas) <- "data"

df <- left_join(datas, df1) %>%
  left_join(., df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute:

```
x<-c(1:9)
y<-c(1:10)

library(qpcR)
qpcR:::cbind.na(x,y)
```

ou

```
qpcR:::rbind.na(x,y) # para linhas
```